# How to create a Sitecore Rocks connection to a dev/test environment running in an Azure Web App?

Tags: sitecore-rocks

How does one *(if possible)* hook up their Sitecore Rocks with a dev/test environment?

I already have it set up for my local dev environment, but would like to also have it for my Dev/Test environments which are running in Azure Web Apps.

[image]